# Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "background" elementui el-pagination

Tags: vue.js, element

I'm using the Element UI [el-pagination](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/pagination) component. But when I try to remove the background, it returns a console error.

**Code**

```
<el-pagination
    class="mt-4"
    :page-size="20"
    :pager-count="11"
    layout="prev, pager, next"
    :total="1000"
    background=false
></el-pagination>
```

**Error**

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "background". Expected Boolean, got String with value "false".

I also tried `:background=false` but it is not working (not removing the background).

Comment: `background` is `false` by default, so you don't need to set it explicitly. What is the "background" you are actually trying to remove?

Comment: @tony19 the pagination background. Currently, when I don't set it, the background is white. I can see it since the background of the body is a bit gray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `background` prop is `false` by default, so setting it `false` won't have the effect you're looking for, which seems to be removing the background color  (making it transparent).

You can make the background transparent with CSS:

```css
.el-pagination button,
.el-pager .el-icon,
.el-pager .number {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/qBmbEzm)